# How to make a column, row or cell editable in a GlazedLists/JTable in java?

Tags: java, swing, glazedlists

Can any one drop a line of code to show how to make a GlazdJTable's cell editable?

```
JTable table = new Jtable();
    TableFormat tableFormat = GlazedLists.tableFormat(properties, headers);
    model = new EventTableModel<Artikel>(filterList, tableFormat);
    selectionModel = new EventSelectionModel<Artikel>(filterList);

    table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
    table.setModel(model);
```

// **how to set table cell editable?**

**Note:** I know that TableFormat must implement the WritableTableFormat interface. but i don't know should i create a custom table format or it is possble to set the Jtable cell editable just like a JTable.

Comment: *"Can any one drop a line of code.."*  <DWS>Sorry, no. It takes **2** lines of code to do that.</DWS>

Comment: Cool let's be 2 lines of code.

Comment: DWS -> Dripping With Sarcasm.

Comment: What does DWS stand for?

DWS: 
Driving While Suspended
      
DWS: 
Delphi Web Script
      
DWS: 
Distributed Wargaming System
      
DWS: 
Driving While Sleeping
      
DWS: 
Driving While Sleeping
      
DWS: 
Dripping With Sarcasm
      
DWS: 
Driver's Weight Sensor
      
DWS: 
Dry Wet Snow
      
DWS: 
Driver Working Space
      
DWS: 
Drivers Weight Sensor
      
DWS: 
Disaster Warning Satellite

Comment: @itro have the answers enabled you to make any progress yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to use a [WritableTableFormat](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/gui/WritableTableFormat.html). The EventTableModel checks to see whether the table format is a WritableTableFormat and if so delegates the isEditable() question to that (as described in the [EventTableModel docs](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/swing/EventTableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29)). Otherwise EventTableModel assumes the table is not editable.

At the moment you're using the GlazedLists.tableFormat() convenience method rather than instantiating your own TableFormat. That's fine, there is a method precisely for this case where you specify whether each column is editable by passing in an array of booleans. See the [GlazedLists.tableFormat(String[] propertyNames, String[] columnLabels, boolean[] editable) documentation](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/GlazedLists.html#tableFormat%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 2):

Override `TableModel's` method
`public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)` to return true for editable and false for the rest cells.

Comment: My model is a default EventTableModel , not a custom EventTableModel to be able to Override the model. If i'm wrong just correct me please?

Comment: API shows public class `EventTableModel<E> extends AbstractTableModel
implements ListEventListener<E>`, then suggestion by StanislavL could be correct